# Connected but no path-connected components

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there an infinite Borel subset of plane which is connected but whose only path connected components are singletons?

I know that a Bernstein set is a non-Borel example of such a set. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

A [pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) is an example of a compact connected subset of the plane that is totally path-disconnected.

Answer (score 8):

I think your assumption should include that the set contains at least two points, otherwise there is a trivial example ...

Eric already mentioned the pseudo-arc, which is of course a perfect answer. Allow me to add a historical discussion, and some more elementary examples.

In addition to the pseudo-arc, any hereditarily [indecomposable continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum) has your property, by definition. However, there are also many other plane continua (compact and connected subsets of the plane) with this property, including ones that are hereditarily **decomposable**. I believe Nadler's book on continuum theory has such an example in the exercises, but I do not have it to hand right now.

The first construction of a continuum not containing any curves - a modification of the $\sin(1/x)$-continuum - seems to have been made by Janiczewski in 1912 (["Über die Begriffe Linie und Fläche"](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1912.2/Main/icm1912.2.0126.0128.ocr.pdf), in the Proceedings of the 5th ICM). This continuum is hereditarily decomposable, and is probably the first example of a set with the properties you mention.

Since you are not asking for the set to be compact, easier examples are possible. Indeed, any space having an [Explosion or dispersion point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point) will trivially have the desired property. In particular, the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) is a simple example. Another example is given by the set of endpoints of the Lelek fan, together with its top (which has an explosion point).