# A connected subset in the plane without arcs

Tags: gn.general-topology

I am wondering if there exists a connected subset $A$ in the plane (which is not an atom $\{x\}$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$) with the property that every continuous map $\gamma : [0,1] \to A$ is constant.

Comment: I would start with the irrationals product with themselves, and see if I could add countable many points with one coordinate rational to foil a pair of separating sets. Also, arrange that the points added are far enough apart to prove no arc present. Alternatively, look at something like a fan of Knaster-Kuratowski.  Gerhard "Is A Fan Of Counterexamples" Paseman, 2019.12.30.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213208/connected-but-no-path-connected-components

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) will do (use the notation as in the link): if there is a $t$ such that $\gamma(t)\neq p$ then there is an interval $I$ around $t$ such that $p\notin\gamma[I]$. Project $\gamma[I]$ down to the Cantor set; by continuity and connectedness of $I$ the image is one point $c$, so $\gamma[I]\subseteq X_c$. But $X_c$ is totally disconnected, so $\gamma[I]$ consists of just one point, $x$ say.  This shows that $\{t:\gamma(t)=x\}$ is  open; as it is also closed it is $[0,1]$.
The other case has $\gamma$ constant with value $p$.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question.